# yum update on CentOS complains about "Multilib version problems" of "nss-softokn-freebl"

Tags: yum, centos7

On last Friday morning, I tried a "yum update" on my CentOS laptop, and it reported this:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, verify
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repo1.dal.innoscale.net
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.lstn.net
 * extras: mirror.unl.edu
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.spro.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.16.2.3-13.el7_1 will be updated
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.16.2.3-14.2.el7_2 will be an update
---> Package python-ecdsa.noarch 0:0.11-3.el7.centos will be obsoleted
---> Package python2-ecdsa.noarch 0:0.13-4.el7 will be obsoleting
---> Package tzdata.noarch 0:2016c-1.el7 will be updated
---> Package tzdata.noarch 0:2016d-1.el7 will be an update
---> Package tzdata-java.noarch 0:2016c-1.el7 will be updated
---> Package tzdata-java.noarch 0:2016d-1.el7 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
   cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
   pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

     1. You have an upgrade for nss-softokn-freebl which is missing some
    dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
    solve this by installing an older version of nss-softokn-freebl of the
    different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
    yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
    requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
    --exclude nss-softokn-freebl.otherarch ... this should give you an error
    message showing the root cause of the problem.

     2. You have multiple architectures of nss-softokn-freebl installed, but
    yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
    If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
    can remove the one with the missing update and everything
    will work.

     3. You have duplicate versions of nss-softokn-freebl installed already.
    You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

   ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
   this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
   do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
   much more problems).

   Protected multilib versions: nss-softokn-freebl-3.16.2.3-14.2.el7_2.i686 != nss-softokn-freebl-3.16.2.3-13.el7_1.x86_64
```

I asked about this on #centos, and someone gave me some exploratory advice, but no real solution.

Comment: Did you try what the error suggest in point 1? (ie `yum update --exclude nss-softokn-freebl.i686`)

Comment: Wasn't sure if I should, but I just did, since you asked. That seemed to do something useful, installing a python package (a replacement, apparently), and updating two tzdata packages.  However, when I then ran "yum update" again after this, it reported the exact thing I report above.

Comment: yep it means you are in the situation described by scenario 1: you have both i686 and x86_64 archs of nss-softokn-freebl and only an update for one of the two can be found. If you can, try to `yum erase` the i686 package (if it does not pull in too many other deps to erase). Alternatively, you may try `yum downgrade nss-softokn-freebl.i686`).

Comment: Ok, erasing the i686 package removed 106 packages, and then a "yum update" after that reported nothing to update. Looks good.  Feel free to summarize the required changes in an answer, or I will, given a sufficient delay.

Comment: let me see if there is a duplicate first

Answer (score 7):

I experienced the very same issue on a Fedora 20 system (run in a docker container) when trying to install i686 development libraries. Reason were two not matching versions for x86_64 and i686, respectively.

```
Protected multilib versions: nss-softokn-freebl-3.19.1-1.0.fc20.i686 != nss-softokn-freebl-3.19.2-1.0.fc20.x86_64
```

For me it helped to call

```
yum distribution-synchronization
```

That automatically downgraded the x86_64 version. After that
I could install with

```
yum install nss-softokn-freebl.i686
```

and

```
yum list installed | grep nss-softokn-freebl
```

showed now:

```
nss-softokn-freebl.i686      3.19.1-1.0.fc20         @updates
nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64    3.19.1-1.0.fc20         @updates
```

Problem solved.